# Node.js with Forever and node-dev

Tags: bash, services, node.js

Seems like it should be a really simple one, but:

How can I run a node.js application with node-dev and forever.js

```
forever start node-dev app.js
```

doesn't work.

Ideally I'd have this as an init.d service too if there is a way of facilitating that, but I'll probably just write that part myself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command default https://github.com/foreverjs/forever so you'd have to do something like `forever start -c node-dev app.js`